# Access Linking Subform to Tab Control in Main Form

Tags: sql, forms, vba, ms-access

I am using Access 2007 at work.  I have a main form with 5 different Tabs in the Tab Control thing.  I want each of the tabs to have the same subform in them, but it filters differently based on what tab you are on.  Ideally I'd like the subform to be linked to just a table, not a form or a query, but as long as it works well I'm flexible.  This table is for Comments.

Main form = frm_CE
Table I want to put in as subform = tbl_AllComments

Is this possible?  If not, are there any other ways at looking at this that would accomplish the same end goal?

Thanks so much

Comment: Is the main form bound to a table?
How should the comments be filtered?  I.e. is there a relationship between the main table and the tbl_AllComments table?

Comment: Hi, thanks for asking. The main form frm_CE is bound to tbl_CE. There is a relationship between tbl_CE and tbl_AllComments, by Loan Number. BUT, I want the comments to be filtered by Document Type, and there is no field in tbl_CE for that, nor can there be unless I rethink the whole thing.

Comment: The way the subform works is it links to one or more fields in both tables to work out the filtering

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't be able to update any information if the table is opened simultaneously 5 times.  If it's at all possible, I'd suggest using a Combo Box to allow your users to filter based on any number of criteria, and then pass the SelectedValue of the Combo Box into the RecordSource of the form:

```
Dim MySQL as String

MySQL = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyField = '" & Me.MyComboBox.SelectedValue & "'"
Me.MySubForm.RecordSource = MySQL
```

In doing this, there would be no need for tabs, and there would be no potential locking issues.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the responses.  I ended up doing something different.  I created 5 different subforms with the same table in them.  Then, for each tab, the subform is linked by loan #, and filtered by document type.  Seems to work great!